# Bubble sort using c

Tags: c, sorting

I tried to do bubble sort using c/c++. It shows the wrong output. I couldn't figure out where the bug is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

int main()
{
    int arr[]={26,27,2,38,44,4,19};
    int n= sizeof arr/sizeof(int);
    int swapped;
    int unsorted_index= n-1, temp;
    do{
        swapped=false;
        for(int i=0; i< unsorted_index-1; i++)
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            {
              temp=arr[i];
              arr[i]=arr[i+1];
              arr[i+1]=temp;
              swapped=true;
            }
        unsorted_index--;
      } while(swapped || unsorted_index);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
       printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

it shows the output:
2 4 26 27 38 44 19

instead of:
2 4 19 26 27 38 44

Comment: Pick a language. It's almost C, except for the `<cstdio>`, and certainly not C++ because you redefine C++ keywords.

Comment: Triple-check your indexing.

Comment: This is an excellent time to learn how to use your debugger if you haven't.

Comment: You risk annoying quite a lot of people by tagging C and C++. The person suffering most from the kind of code you show and the apparent confusion about which compiler to use is yourself. I recommend to clean up your understanding and get rid of the confusion. That is not easy. But maybe a viable path is to pick one of the two languages and study some HelloWorlds and tutorials on the topics you are interested in.

Comment: `<cstdio>` is not a C header, so I removed the `c` tag. (Also, `bool` is not a built-in type in C.)

Comment: Isn't it illegal to `#define` a reserved keyword such as `true` and `false` in C++? Or the rule is different in "c/c++"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your loop is not traversing the complete array. To do this:

> Replace "unsorted_index= n-1" to "unsorted_index= n".

output:

> 2 4 19 26 27 38 44